# Django : after include tag getting critical Error

Tags: django, django-templates, django-tagging

after i'm using include tag in django template, i'm getting error.

error:

```
RecursionError at /home/
maximum recursion depth exceeded
Error during template rendering
```

my base.html file .

```
<html>
{% load static %}
<some static css here>
{% include "inc/header.html" %}
     {% block header %} HEADER {% endblock header %}
<some static js here>
</html>
```

my header file is

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
<p> test header</p>
```

Comment: add your related `views.py` files.

Answer (score 0):

You are right now doing two things at the same time, you are extending 'base.html' file, while in the same time you are including 'header.html'.

This is why you get recursion problems.

For things to work properly you need to remove {% include %} block of code. So your header file looks like

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block header %}
<p> Test Header </p>
{% endblock %}
```

While your base.html doesnt need 'HEADER' beetwen your {% block header %} tags, so it should look like:

```
<html>
{% load static %}
<some static css here>
{% block header %}{% endblock %}
<some static js here>
</html>
```

Comment: i try to only include header file but still gettin error

Comment: As I said, don't use "Include" use only extends, like shown above

Comment: yes but if i want to include html file? how fix this? i want to create inc/header.html and include it to base.html

Comment: You dont need to 'include' it. Django understands the {% block name %} notation, and it will extend the base.html with elements contained in the header.html template within {% block header %} {% endblock%} tags